# bring payment id generated in a database to frontend

Tags: javascript, php

Good afternoon,

I am implementing a payment processor, and I need to bring the corresponding payment ID that is automatically generated in the backend.

I have the frontend and a database created in php.
In the frontend using JS I request the data to the backend, but I can't get the ID.

I tried to pass the id in php to a js variable through a script and then with localstorage send it to the frontend but it didn't work.

```
$payment->transaction_amount = (float) $form_data['transaction_amount'];
$payment->token = $form_data['token'];
$payment->description = "Pago";
$payment->installments = (int)$form_data['installments'];
$payment->payment_method_id = $form_data['payment_method_id'];
$payment->issuer_id = (int)$form_data['issuer_id'];

$payer = new MercadoPago\Payer();
$payer->email = $form_data['payer']['email'];
$payer->identification = array(
    "type" => $form_data['payer']['identification']['type'],
    "number" => $form_data['payer']['identification']['number']
);
$payer->first_name = $form_data['cardholderName'];
$payment->payer = $payer;

$payment->save();

$response = array(
    'status' => $payment->status,
    'status_detail' => $payment->status_detail,
    'id' => $payment->id
);

$id = ($response['id']); //separating the id

echo ($id); // id to bring to the frontend
```

JS:

```
<script>
payId = "<?php echo $id ?>"; //pass the id from php to js
payId = localStorage.setItem('idPago', payId); //I save it with localstorage
</script>
```

FrontEnd:

```
            const renderCardPaymentBrick = async (bricksBuilder) => {
            const settings = {
                initialization: {
                    //tenes que fijarte si esto esta en pesos o
                    amount: price, // monto a ser pago

                    // preferenceId: "" // where i need to bring the id
                },
                callbacks: {
                    onReady: () => {
                        // callback llamado cuando Brick esté listo
                    },
                    onSubmit: (cardFormData) => {
                        cardFormData['cardholderName'] = document.getElementsByName("HOLDER_NAME")[0].value;
                        // ejemplo de envío de los datos recolectados por el Brick a su servidor
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            fetch("./api/mp.php", {
                                    method: "POST",
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    },
                                    body: JSON.stringify(cardFormData)
                                })
                                .then((response) => {
                                    console.log(response);
                                    resolve();
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.log(error);
                                    // tratar respuesta de error al intentar crear el pago
                                    reject();
                                })
                        });
                    },
                    onError: (error) => {
                        // callback llamado para todos los casos de error de Brick
                    },
                },
            };
            const cardPaymentBrickController = await bricksBuilder.create('cardPayment', 'cardPaymentBrick_container', settings);
        };
```

sorry if some of the annotations are in spanish, but what matters is the preferenceId at the beginning of the frontend.

I appreciate any help! thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the data from there by creating a hidden input.
For example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="payment_id">
```

JS:

```
var payId = document.getElementById("payment_id").value;
payId = localStorage.setItem('idPago', payId);
```